# Chromium: No microphone devices

Tags: linux, google-chrome, arch-linux, flash, microphone

I am using chromium on ArchLinux, and I have tested that with ffmpeg the microphone works and I can record a wav file.

But when it comes to using online flash recorder, it shows that "Microphone access error" and chromium tells me that "System has denied https://www.speakpipe.com/ to access to microphone" and "No microphone devices" on select microphone filed.

[image: Screenshot]

Excuse my not knowing how to make chromium into English, so I translate the screenshot into English with Gimp XD

So let's back to the question: how can I make it work in chromium, which means flash can record my voice and chromium can find the microphone? Maybe some packages I have forgotten to install, so let me know which package is vital.

Comment: "Excuse my not knowing how to make chromium into English" - you can open terminal window, and run commands: `export LC_ALL=C` and then `chromium`.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe add chromium user in group 'audio' to be able to use your mic in chromium. But I don't know which user is used by chromium.